# Determine one triple of positive integer

Tags: number-theory

Note that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1$ and $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{6\times 7}$ and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{42}=1$.

Determine one triple $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers with $1000<x<y<z<2000$ and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{45}=1$.

A friend of mine asked me this question. I have only been able to guess one solution but $x,y,z$ doesn't fall into the range.

Note: This question is meant to be done within 10-15min and without a computer.

Comment: What's your solution and how did you get it?

Comment: Set $x=y=z=\frac{1}{1890}$ would be one solution. I have tried to expand on it such as slightly tweaking the value of $x$ and $z$ but that got me no where.

Comment: gammatester found three triples. looks acceptable to me...

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions for
$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{45} = 1$
in the required range, I
found them by exhaustive search:
$$x=1771,\;y=1932,\;z=1980$$
$$x=1806,\;y=1892,\;z=1980$$
$$x=1830,\;y=1891,\;z=1953$$

Comment: What do you mean by exhaustive search? Did you use a computer?

Comment: Probably so.  Looping over $x,y$ and calculating $z$ and checking whether it was integral would take about a half million iterations-easy for a computer but not so by hand.

Comment: This has to be do-able by hand.

Comment: Yes of course the search is done with a computer, I don't have the time to check 165668499 triples by hand. And if you do not want to use computers you have to say it, as you have done in your edit meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this isn't a solution, but it seems that there is no general way to solve Diophantine Equations of this type.  The [Erdős-Strauss *conjecture*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) claims that there always exists integral solutions to $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{4}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (in this case, $x^{-1}+y^{-1}+z^{-1}=4/2520$).  Here is the [OEIS link](http://oeis.org/A073101) to the amount of solutions found for each $n$.